# Android memory mapped file with vertices

Tags: android, opengl-es, memory-mapped-files

I am trying to render vertices stored in a big file (approx 50Mb). The file layout is optimized so i can take a slice and give it to opengl to render a triangel strip directly.

This works in the emulator, but when I run the same code in my magic (android 1.5) it crashes with a SIGBUS in libhgl.so. Sounds like a driver issue?

I have tried to manually copy the vertices to a local buffer (non mem mapped), works but it takes eons of time, 300-600 ms.

Anyone have any experience?

Comment: Is the emulator also set up to run 1.5?

Comment: SIGBUS suggests that the file got unmapped.  What address is the file mapped at, and what address is the driver failing at?

Comment: I was running the emulator with 2.2 and just tried running it with 1.5 but I get the same result (it runs fine).

Comment: I/DEBUG   ( 3087): signal 7 (SIGBUS), fault addr 00000000

Comment: I/DEBUG   ( 3087): stack:
I/DEBUG   ( 3087):     48790c8c  80431548  /system/lib/libhgl.so
I/DEBUG   ( 3087):     48790c90  00000011
I/DEBUG   ( 3087):     48790c94  41042e50